# Convert List<string>[] to double[,]

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to convert an Array of Lists

```
public static List<string>[] Data { get; private set; }
```

to a 2 dimensional Array of double.

My attempt looks like this:

```
var data = Data.Select(c => c.Select(double.Parse).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

But with this method i got as a result a `double[][]`, an array of arrays.
How can i convert to a 2-dimensional array `double[,]`?

Each `List<string>` is a column.

For example `Data` is an array of 10 `List<string>`. Each List has 160.000 entries. I want to convert this to a 10x160.000 matrix.

Thanks in ahead.

Comment: Use a loop like in the linked question/answer and insert the `double.Parse()`.

Comment: Multidimensional array doesn't work well with linq. You need to use a for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My idea was to avoid a for loop (2 of them), to gain speed improvements. But i tried the solution above, and it works well. So thank you for your help.